# mdmsetup returns exit status 1

Tags: lightdm, display-manager, mdm

I'd like to install and use `mdm` over `lightdm` with Cinnamon.

I've installed `mdm`, but `gksudo mdmsetup` just opens a dialogue requesting authentication, then immediately exits with code `1`. There's nothing in any system logs.

Am I missing a package, or should I configure by hand?

---

Here are the results requested in the comments:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mint-kitty 4.2.0-24-generic #29-Ubuntu 15.10 SMP Mon Jan 11 18:00:07 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ apt-cache policy mdm
mdm:
  Installed: 0.1.3-2.1
  Candidate: 0.1.3-2.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.1.3-2.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ which mdmsetup
process terminated with exit status 2
```

Comment: have a look at this how-to here if you missed something during installation maybe: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/install-mint-display-manager-mdm-in.html

Comment: there is no such package `mint-mdm-themes` or `mdm-themes` even after adding that repository.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that but visiting the launchpad repository I can clearly see all packages in place including the 2 packages you just mentioned. Not sure how much experience you have with ubuntu or linux in general but I didn't really asked youa ctually to perform the how-to. I just suggested to cross-check with what you did and see if you have missed anything. And for the record, here you can see the repo packages: https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+index?batch=75&memo=225&start=225

Comment: @cat: I guess you're trying wrong command to **configure mdm**. Instead of `gksudo mdmsetup` just try **sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm** and then select **mdm** from the list and press **ok**. Then try to reboot your system. if `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm` doesn't work then you can also try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and then select **mdm** from the list.

Comment: The package won't appear in the package list until you run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: @user4901968 I'm aware; I did update.

Comment: @cat please [edit] your question and add: Ubuntu release you have, output of `apt-cache policy mdm` and `which mdmsetup`

Comment: @Sneetsher okay, there you go.

Comment: Note that even after adding the repo, both `apt search mdmsetup` and `apt install mdmsetup` return `E: Unable to locate package mdmsetup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another package in the Ubuntu official repository/universe with the same name `mdm`, see [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=names&keywords=mdm)

> Package mdm
>
> ```
> xenial (utils): Utilities for single-host parallel shell scripting [universe]
> 0.1.3-2.1: amd64 i386
> ```

Possibly, you have installed the wrong package. Check:

```
sudo apt-cache policy mdm
which mdmsetup
```

I think this should be reported to Mint dev as bug.

Well now it is clear that you don't have mint mdm installed.

1. Remove mdm got from official repository

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge mdm
   ```
2. Download mint mdm and its related themes from a mirror or the Mint official repository:

   http://packages.linuxmint.com/search.php?keyword=mdm&release=Sarah&section=any
3. Install it using software center (double click) or command, example:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i mdm_2.0.7+rosa_amd64.deb
   ```

Comment: `dpkg: regarding mdm_2.0.4+rafaela_amd64.deb containing mdm:
 mdm conflicts with gdm
  gdm (version 3.16.2-0ubuntu2) is present and installed.
`
Can I safely remove `gdm`?

Comment: @cat As you have lightdm it OK? In case mdm didn't work and you couldn't get graphic interface, reboot to recovery mode and set lightdm instead or reinstall gdm.

Comment: the `mdm` deb requires `mdm-themes` but it has no installation candidate, and it is not available from the PPA mentioned in the other answer either.

Comment: @cat while looking for theme package I noticed that mirror was old. I updated my answer that page also contains the links to theme packages. Sorry I'm far from pc, that why icould't test things before posting.

Comment: Well I *did* accept your answer but I didn't leave enough time between clicks on the the `reward` and `accept` buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't just install mdm you need to type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/mint` then update and type `sudo apt-get install mdm mdm-themes`.
You can use the other official repository or if you have access to the root account. You may be able to run this command without the mdm window.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo apt-get purge mdm
dpkg-reconfigure mdm
```

If that did not work I suggest you type `apt-cache policy mdm` then `which mdmsetup`.

Also try uninstalling lightdm and install mdm. That may also solve your problem. To do this run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mdm
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I can't actually *install* the `mdm` desktop package; when I reconf lightdm I'm only shown `gdm` and `lightdm`

Comment: I'll try building from source.

Comment: You also may want to run all of the commands above, Try using root and see if it won't ask.

Comment: Try looking on packages.ubuntu.com